# Show that the norm $\|\cdot\|_{1}: l_1 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not differentiable at any point of $l_1$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let A be the set of all sequences {${{x_{n}}}$} of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_{n}|<\infty$. Let $$\| {{x_{n}}}  \|_{1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_{n}|.$$  Show that the norm $\|\cdot\|_1: l_{1} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not differentiable at any point of $l_1$.

I have spent a lot of time in question, still don't know how to solve it. Can someone help me solve this question?

Comment: This problem is from my real analysis course,professor gave us this homework problem

Comment: 144600: I did some Math formatting, please let me know the changes are not OK with you.

Comment: Can you prove that $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$?  The idea is approaching from opposing directions.  I believe the same technique should work (I assume you have to consider $h$ to be a $\ell_1$ sequence whose norm is approaching zero).  Carefully pick how that sequence goes to zero... and do it two different ways (getting two different results).

Comment: still have no idea how to use your technique to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the norm is differentiable at $x$. Clearly for all $n$ we have $x_n\neq 0$: otherwise, if $x_n=0$, compose the norm with the function
$\gamma(t):=x+te_n$ ($e_n$ denotes the element of $\ell^1$ whose components all vanish except the $n$-th, which equals $1$). Then $t\mapsto \|\gamma(t)\|$
ought to be differentiable at $0$, but this fails as
$$ \|\gamma(t)\|=\|x\|+|t|. $$

In the same way you discover what the differential should be:
call it $y$; we know that $y\in(\ell^1)^*=\ell^\infty$ and with the same trick of composing with $\gamma$ we get
$$ \alpha(t):=\|\gamma(t)\|=\sum_{m\neq n}|x_m|+|x_n+t| $$
and taking into account that $\alpha'(0)=\langle y,e_n\rangle=y_n$
we obtain $y_n=\text{sgn}(x_n)$.

Now differentiability says that $\|x+h\|=\|x\|+\langle y,h\rangle+o(\|h\|)$, so for some small $\delta>0$ the error term $o(\|h\|)$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}\|h\|$ when $\|h\|<\delta$. 
Since $x\in\ell^1$, we can find some $n$ such that $|x_n|<\frac{\delta}{2}$.
Now choose $h:=-2x_n e_n$ (which satisfies $\|h\|<\delta$) and observe that
$\|x+h\|=\sum_{m\neq n}|x_m|+|x_n-2x_n|=\|x\|$. So
$$\|x\|=\|x+h\|=\|x\|+\langle y,h\rangle +r $$
where the error term $r\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|r|\le\frac{1}{2}\|h\|$.
Since
$$\langle y,h\rangle=\text{sgn}(x_n)(-2x_n)=-2|x_n|=-\|h\|,$$
we obtain the contradiction
$$\|x\|=\|x\|+\langle y,h\rangle +r\le \|x\|-\|h\|+\frac{1}{2}\|h\|<\|x\|. $$